# CiviMail SMTP error

Tags: civimail, smtp

I have configured SMTP on CiviCRM, All the details are correct I have received the test mail from CiviCRM mentioned that "SMTP settings are correct".

But If I tried to send a campaign or an email to contact getting below error:

Failed to set sender: [my admin email address] [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 501, response: 5.7.1 ... Permission denied)]

Comment: Check that the SMTP ports are open on your server and the SMTP server.....

Comment: Yes, ports are open. I have received the SMTP configuration mail from CiviCRM